# Magento 2--the requested component ("0") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation

Tags: magento2

hi Magento expert friends, 
recently I have migrated magento 1 to Magento-2 2.1.0 version. with 9000 products and 20000 orders.
I Migrated with Magento migration tool.
everything is fine so far except, "the requested component ("0") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation." error.
when i try to open a product in admin, it shows this error.
can you please help me to solve it ?

Thanks a lot to all Magento experts

Answer (score 1):

Check `eav_attribute` database column and make sure you have no `0` value for column `frontend_input`.

If you find one you can replace with `text`.