# Magento 2--the requested component (“0”) is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation

Tags: magento2

Recently I have migrated magento 1 to Magento-2 2.1.0 version. with 9000 products and 20000 orders. I Migrated with Magento migration tool. Everything is fine so far except this error:

> the requested component ("0") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

When I try to open a product in admin, it shows this error. Can you please help me to solve it ?

Comment: Check the answer here on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881524/magento-2-the-requested-component-0-is-not-found-before-using-you-must-ad